# Database is not accessible on server but working well on localhost

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have developed my first website in ASP.NET with C#. It's a small website which uses Microsoft SQL server 2008 for database and I've deployed it on a free hosting site [www.somee.com](http://www.somee.com). It's database is working well on my computer but when I try to access the database on server it gives following error:

```
[ A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. 
The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. 
(provider: SQL Network Interfaces, 
error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)].
```

I have updated connection string of the database in web.config and I've used getConString() method for accessing connection string like this:

```
public string getConString()
{
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
}
```

What can I do to solve this problem.

Wbsite url is: [www.easyways.somee.com](http://www.easyways.somee.com)

Comment: can you share the syntax of your connection string ??

Comment: @Don you can find the whole connection string of your somee database from its control panel. Just paste that code into web.config.

Comment: @yogi here is the connection string that the hosting site provided me: "workstation id=easywaysdata.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=easyways_db;pwd=********;data source=easywaysdata.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=easywaysdata"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan I've used that connection string in my web.config file. But I'm not sure that is there any other place where I need to update that connection string.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all of you for your support. I got the solution for my problem. Actually I did something wrong either in creating a database or in using connection string.

Now I recreated a blank database and then I executed the SQL script that I created for my database by navigating to  "User -> Managed products -> MS SQL -> Databases -> (Database name) -> New SQL query from file". And also updated the new connection string in web.config file.

This is the connection string I used now:

```
"workstation id=dataeasyways.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=easyways_db;pwd=********;data source=dataeasyways.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=dataeasyways"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider provides the connection information for you (in the case of your hosting provider you can see their [Help Page](http://somee.com/DOKA/DoHelpTopics.aspx?docode=false&thnid=103) here, which shows you how to connect to their DB.

Basically it boils down to logging into their control panel.

```
In "User menu" navigate to "User -> Managed products -> MS SQL -> Databases -> (Database name)".
```

Also remember that since this is a remote database there is a small chance that its firwalled from the outside world and only local webservers can access the database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have already updated that connection string in web.config file that was provided by the hosting site. Is there any other place rather than web.config file where I need to update the connection string?

Comment: In theory no, it depends entirely on your web.config file though. But most of the time the connection string is only specified in the connectionstrings sectiongroup and everything references that.